# RESTapi's and Multilingual representations --- POST, PUT and DELETE

Tags: rest, internationalization, http-headers, multilingual, put

So, it's quite common to use content-negotiation to get a different language representation for the same resource:

```
GET /resource/12345 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-GB;q=9.0, fr;q=0.8, *
Accept: application/json
```

which would give back a representation in British, French or any other language.

```
{ "greeting": "Bon Jour" }
```

And i think this is the right way to do it, so far, i am fine with the concept of content-negotiation.

Somehow, somewhere "Bon Jour" must have been entered... now, somehow, using REST, i want to add also the British representation.

## Proposal

I was tempted to introduce:

```
PUT /resource/12345 HTTP/1.1
Content-Language: en-GB
Content-Type: application/json

{ "greeting" : "Good Morning" }
```

And one could selectively delete on translation with

```
DELETE /resource/12345 HTTP/1.1
Content-Language: pt_BR           # Portuguese Brasil
```

Or delete the entire resource without specifying `Content-Language`

## However

These ways to work with multilingual versions of a resource are nowhere being described. There is nothing in the RFCs. Also, `Content-Language` is mostly considered as a response header, although the old RFC did call it an 'entity' header.

## Request for Comments

Please feel free to comment on this proposal in using the `Content-Language` header field to specify in which specific language the HTTP method should be performed. Naturally, a `GET` does not have a content body and therefore the content language does not need to be specified.

## Question

What is common / best practice, where possible avoiding to add the language in the URL?

Comment: It seems that finding an answer on this topic constantly points in the direction of using a language identifier in the URL --- I still believe it is not needed at all. --- I found a question that has almost the same concept, but that is still unanswered too: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232596/how-to-indicate-to-a-web-server-the-language-of-a-resource

Comment: I've decided to write a paper on how to handle the non-safe requests for a 'multilingual' api using `Content-Language` as a parameter to tell the server what exactly should do with the resource and the language specific variant

Answer (score 0):

There have been several approaches at Web authoring and handling different representations of resources, based on Content-Language as well as other content negotiation features.

One approach was [Delta-V](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-deltav-versioning-12#page-81) and its [Variant management](http://www.webdav.org/deltav/protocol/draft-ietf-deltav-variants-xx.1.htm).

However, this was never well-enough defined to be interoperable, and was dropped from the DeltaV standard.

Another discussion was around having a PATCH body format specifically defined for modifying resource metadata.  A bunch of work would have to be done to define the format and how to express how many variants should exist and how to assign content information to representations.

The gist of the repeated discussions AFAICR is that in order to do Web authoring over HTTP and support content variants would require quite a bit of work, and not just defining how to use a header on PUT/DELETE.  Authoring clients would need a way to get lists of variants and how they varied.

In contrast, as you've seen with various implementations of Web servers that serve documents out of file systems or databases, implementors have come up with various non-HTTP ways of authoring language variants, some more and some less RESTful in the way browsers GET the language variants.  Filesystems aren't typically capable of supporting variants without a lot of superstructure, and content negotiation doesn't seem to be a top feature of Web servers or CMS servers.

You might try searching some of the archives of IETF HTTP-related mailing lists or posting to those lists; that's where people tend to discuss the theoretical and architectural aspects of this, rather than just worrying about local implementation tradeoffs.